# writing in Sharelatex, got "File ended while scanning use of \@xargdef." error

Tags: errors, sharelatex

While trying to compute my report in [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com) I got the error stating

> "File ended while scanning use of \@xargdef."

I've tried looking through the document for an error in curly bracketing `{}` but I can't seem to find any, haven't been able to find anything on what `\@xargdef` is either, any help is greatly appreciated.

I made a gist for the code of the document since it is quite long here: https://gist.github.com/ZzimonNanoq/527855642ed275fc0c67

the error message in its entirety is as follows:

```
File ended while scanning use of \@xargdef.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> main.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
7316 strings out of 495028
109339 string characters out of 6181497
229851 words of memory out of 5000000
10500 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3940 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
42i,0n,43p,1192b,38s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: It's almost certainly possible that you can reproduce the same error with a smaller code (and then you can post it in your question, which people usually prefer) -- can you try to make your document smaller, such that it has the same problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems noted in your source document.

1. Definition of `\namesigdate` is missing a closing brace.  The correct code would be:

   `\newcommand{\namesigdate}[2][5cm]{%
     \begin{tabular}{@{}p{#1}@{}}
       #2 \\[2\normalbaselineskip] \hrule \\[15pt]
     \end{tabular}}`
2. Either `\begin{comment}` used unnecessarily on line 61 or it is not ended promptly in the document.

Fixing the above two issues will solve the problems.

Comment: The closing brace fixed it, thanks! The \begin{comment} parts were just failed attempts at finding the error ^^'.

Comment: You can just try by removing it OR add appropriate 'end comment'

Comment: I mean `\end{comment}`.

Comment: yeah, I had some  end comment sections in there but I just forgot to remove the \begin{comment} as well. Thanks :)